# How to make lists contain only distinct element in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list in Python, how can I make it's values unique?

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/) if you want to preserve the ordering.

Comment: Please fix the title of your question.  You're not talking about make lists distinct.  You're talking about making list **items** distinct.

Comment: Why do you need list in the first place? Maybe set() or dict() are enough.

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/1129682) for more information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order

Answer (score 393, accepted):

The simplest is to convert to a set then back to a list:

```
my_list = list(set(my_list))
```

One disadvantage with this is that it won't preserve the order. You may also want to consider if a set would be a better data structure to use in the first place, instead of a list.

Comment: i am wrong or with python3k the values will be preserved, cause set now are sorted?

Comment: @Ant Dictionary key order is preserved from Python 3.6, but it says "the order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon". Since they're both based on hashes, I'd think set would be the same, but it's not mentioned, so apparently not: https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html

Comment: Preserve order and functional way: 
In 
`[23]: from functools import reduce`

`In [24]: reduce(lambda acc,elem: acc+[elem] if not elem in acc else acc , [2,1,2,3,3,3,4,5], [])`

`Out[24]: [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: The order of the list gets lost this way

Comment: worth mentioning that this doesn't work if the list contains a list.

Answer (score 33):

Modified versions of http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark

To preserve the order:

```
def f(seq): # Order preserving
  ''' Modified version of Dave Kirby solution '''
  seen = set()
  return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
```

OK, now how does it work, because it's a little bit tricky here `if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)`:

```
In [1]: 0 not in [1,2,3] and not print('add')
add
Out[1]: True
```

Why does it return True? print (and set.add) returns nothing:

```
In [3]: type(seen.add(10))
Out[3]: <type 'NoneType'>
```

and `not None == True`, but:

```
In [2]: 1 not in [1,2,3] and not print('add')
Out[2]: False
```

Why does it print 'add' in [1] but not in [2]? See `False and print('add')`, and doesn't check the second argument, because it already knows the answer, and returns true only if both arguments are True.

More generic version, more readable, generator based, adds the ability to transform values with a function:

```
def f(seq, idfun=None): # Order preserving
  return list(_f(seq, idfun))

def _f(seq, idfun=None):  
  ''' Originally proposed by Andrew Dalke '''
  seen = set()
  if idfun is None:
    for x in seq:
      if x not in seen:
        seen.add(x)
        yield x
  else:
    for x in seq:
      x = idfun(x)
      if x not in seen:
        seen.add(x)
        yield x
```

Without order (it's faster):

```
def f(seq): # Not order preserving
  return list(set(seq))
```

Comment: sort of inner helper function (there was a bug in the code, should be _f instead of _f10 on line 2, thanks for spotting)

Answer (score 31):

one-liner and preserve order

```
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([2,1,1,3]))
```

although you'll need

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Comment: An alternative form is: OrderedDict.fromkeys(my_list).keys()

Comment: @DannyStaple: that works in python 2, but in python 3 it returns a view of the dictionary keys, which might be okay for some purposes, but doesn't support indexing for example.

Comment: The initial one liner will work. The aternative form returns an odict_keys type, which is less useful for this - but can still be converted to a list.

Answer (score 18):

Let me explain to you by an example:

if you have Python list

```
>>> randomList = ["a","f", "b", "c", "d", "a", "c", "e", "d", "f", "e"]
```

and you want to remove duplicates from it.

```
>>> uniqueList = []

>>> for letter in randomList:
    if letter not in uniqueList:
        uniqueList.append(letter)

>>> uniqueList
['a', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

This is how you can remove duplicates from the list.

Comment: +1 because it's the only one that works for types that are unhashable, but do have an __eq__ function (if your types are hashable, use one of the other solutions). Note that it will be slow for very big lists.

Comment: Unless in some special case as Claude explained, this one has the worst performance: O(n^2)

Answer (score 14):

To preserve the order:

```
l = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
result = list()
map(lambda x: not x in result and result.append(x), l)
result
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: In python 3.4 returns an empty list!!!

Comment: map just creates map object (generator), does not execute it.
list(map(....)) forces the execution

Comment: It will produce not optimal performance, due to traversal the result list for each x.

Answer (score 10):

How about **dictionary comprehensions**?

```
>>> mylist = [3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3]

>>> {x:1 for x in mylist}.keys()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**EDIT**
To @Danny's comment: my original suggestion does not keep the keys ordered. If you need the keys sorted, try:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> OrderedDict( (x,1) for x in mylist ).keys()
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
```

which keeps elements in the order by the first occurrence of the element (not extensively tested)

Comment: This would not preserve order - dictionary order (and set order) is determined by the hashing algorithm and not insertion order. I am not sure of the effects of a dictionary comprehension with an OrderedDict type though.

Comment: @DannyStaple True. I added an example using `OrderedDict` and a generator, if ordered output is desired.

Answer (score 5):

The characteristics of sets in Python are that the data items in a set
are unordered and duplicates are not allowed. If you try to add a data item to a set that already contains the data item, Python simply ignores it.

```
>>> l = ['a', 'a', 'bb', 'b', 'c', 'c', '10', '10', '8','8', 10, 10, 6, 10, 11.2, 11.2, 11, 11]
>>> distinct_l = set(l)
>>> print(distinct_l)
set(['a', '10', 'c', 'b', 6, 'bb', 10, 11, 11.2, '8'])
```

Answer (score 3):

If all elements of the list may be used as dictionary keys (i.e. they are all hashable) this is often faster. [Python Programming FAQ](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

```
d = {}
for x in mylist:
    d[x] = 1
mylist = list(d.keys())
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark:

```
def f5(seq, idfun=None):  
    # order preserving
    if idfun is None:
        def idfun(x): return x
    seen = {}
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        marker = idfun(item)
        # in old Python versions:
        # if seen.has_key(marker)
        # but in new ones:
        if marker in seen: continue
        seen[marker] = 1
        result.append(item)
    return result
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to use a set for seen, rather than a dict?

Comment: In Python, sets and dicts are built using hashtables so they are interchangeable in this scenario.  They both provide the same operations (limiting duplicates) and both have the same running time.

Comment: This one is slow, generator version is much faster

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to remove duplicates whilst preserving order is to use [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (Python 2.7+).

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
for x in mylist:
    d[x] = True
print d.iterkeys()
```