# Removing duplicates in lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, duplicates, intersection

How can I check if a list has any duplicates and return a new list without duplicates?

Comment: related: [How to use multiprocessing to drop duplicates in a very big list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59762414/9059420)

Comment: Interestingly, none of the top answers here provides an answer to the actual question: create a new list with only items that are not duplicated in the original list. I read that as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4]` -> `[1, 3, 5]`, as 2 and 4 are duplicated.

Comment: @9769953 Given what you say, would it make sense to use [Rev 11](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7961363/11), but keep only the first sub-question (i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 1]  →  [1, 2, 3]`) that is answered by the top answers? The accepted answer hints at a possible way to accomplish the second sub-question (i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 1]  →  [2, 3]`). As it stands, the question and top answer are paradoxically not in exactly sync.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I prefer to keep the original question. Also, rev. 11 changes the question to fit the answers more, but not necessarily fit the original question. I guess then it depends how much of a forum/mailing list style you'd like SO to be, or how close to a tips'n'tricks website (with very pure questions and answers). I don't think either is achievable.

Comment: After going back and reading rev 1, I can't fathom how the question could be read as saying anything about whether `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4]` should transform to `[1, 3, 5]` or to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, or if order matters, or anything else. In fact, despite the title "Python removing duplicates in lists", it doesn't seem like OP wanted to remove duplicates from within the **same** list at all. Rather, it looks like OP wanted to take **two** lists e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[1, 3, 4]`, and remove from the first *those which are present in the second*, to get `[2]`.

Comment: In other words, that would have made the question a duplicate of [Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209), which was much better asked from the start. But it seems like almost everyone saw a different question from that.

Comment: The answer strongly depends on the use-case. Should the order be maintained or not?

Answer (score 2262, accepted):

The common approach to get a unique collection of items is to use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Sets are *unordered* collections of *distinct* objects. To create a set from any iterable, you can simply pass it to the built-in [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) function. If you later need a real list again, you can similarly pass the set to the [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function.

The following example should cover whatever you are trying to do:

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(set(t))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> s = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(set(t) - set(s))
[8, 5, 6, 7]
```

As you can see from the example result, *the original order is not maintained*. As mentioned above, sets themselves are unordered collections, so the order is lost. When converting a set back to a list, an arbitrary order is created.

#### Maintaining order

If order is important to you, then you will have to use a different mechanism. A very common solution for this is to rely on [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep the order of keys during insertion:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(t))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

[Starting with Python 3.7](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html), the built-in dictionary is guaranteed to maintain the insertion order as well, so you can also use that directly if you are on Python 3.7 or later (or CPython 3.6):

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(t))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Note that this may have some overhead of creating a dictionary first, and then creating a list from it. If you don’t actually need to preserve the order, you’re often better off using a set, especially because it gives you a lot more operations to work with. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/216074) for more details and alternative ways to preserve the order when removing duplicates.

---

Finally note that both the `set` as well as the `OrderedDict`/`dict` solutions require your items to be *hashable*. This usually means that they have to be immutable. If you have to deal with items that are not hashable (e.g. list objects), then you will have to use a slow approach in which you will basically have to compare every item with every other item in a nested loop.

Comment: add this to example, t = [3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8], shows the difference clearly!

Comment: "...overhead of creating a dictionary first... If you don’t actually need to preserve the order, you’re better off using a set." — I profiled this because I was curious if it was actually true. My timings show that indeed the set is slightly faster: 1.12 µs per loop (set) vs 1.53 µs per loop (dict) over 1M loops with an absolute time difference of about 4s over 1M iterations. So if you're doing this in a tight inner loop you may care, otherwise probably not.

Comment: @millerdev I was going to say something like _“overhead does not only mean timing”_ but then I checked and it appears that a keyed dictionary is actually smaller in memory than a set with the same elements. At least in current versions of Python. That’s really surprising – but yes, it’s a good point! Thanks!

Comment: This solves the issue with *unhashable* types (where t is a list of dicts): `[dict(d) for d in set([frozenset(i.items()) for i in t])]`

Comment: @FredrikErlandsson Note that this highly depends on the actual shape of your dictionaries. If you have a dictionary that contains unhashable values itself, then this won’t be enough.

Comment: @poke time complexity of list(dict.fromkeys(t))?

Comment: @BigDreamz `dict.fromkeys()` creates a dictionary in linear time, and `list()` will create a list from it also in linear time.

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. I am trying to deduplicate a list of lists of strings while maintaining order. @FredrikErlandsson's solution didn't resolve it for me.

Comment: You cannot put lists in sets since lists are mutable and could change (which could affect whether they are duplicate to another list in the set). I would suggest a different approach for a list of lists, e.g. as covered in [this question about removing duplicates from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2213923/216074).

Answer (score 485):

**In Python 2.7**, the new way of removing duplicates from an iterable while keeping it in the original order is:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys('abracadabra'))
['a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd']
```

**In Python 3.5**, the OrderedDict has a C implementation. My timings show that this is now both the fastest and shortest of the various approaches for Python 3.5.

**In Python 3.6**, the regular dict became both ordered and compact.  (This feature is holds for CPython and PyPy but may not present in other implementations).  That gives us a new fastest way of deduping while retaining order:

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys('abracadabra'))
['a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd']
```

**In Python 3.7**, the regular dict is guaranteed to both ordered across all implementations.  **So, the shortest and fastest solution is:**

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys('abracadabra'))
['a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I think this is the only way to keep the items in order.

Comment: @HerberthAmaral: That is very far from true, see [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/480214)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Correcting: I think this is the only *simple* way to keep items in order.

Comment: For this too, the content of the original list must be hashable

Comment: As @Davide mentioned, the original list must hashable. This means, that this does not work for a list of dictionaries.
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'dictlist'`

Comment: If the original list is not hashable, the [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package has [`unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) which works with both hashable and unhashable items.

Comment: Why so many api changes for so important feature in Python?

Answer (score 216):

It's a one-liner: `list(set(source_list))` will do the trick.

A `set` is something that can't possibly have duplicates.

Update: an order-preserving approach is two lines:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict((x, True) for x in source_list).keys()
```

Here we use the fact that `OrderedDict` remembers the insertion order of keys, and does not change it when a value at a particular key is updated. We insert `True` as values, but we could insert anything, values are just not used. (`set` works a lot like a `dict` with ignored values, too.)

Comment: @AdrianKeister: This is true. There are objects that have reasonable equality semantics but are not hashable, e.g. lists. OTOH if we can't have a shortcut like a hastable, we end up with a quadratic algorithm of just comparing every element with all currently known unique elements. This can be totally OK for short inputs, especially with a lot of duplicates.

Comment: Right, exactly. I think your answer would be higher quality if you took this very common use case into account.

Answer (score 120):

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> t
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> s = []
>>> for i in t:
       if i not in s:
          s.append(i)
>>> s
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Note that this method works in O(n^2) time and is thus very slow on large lists.

Answer (score 107):

If you don't care about the order, just do this:

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))
```

A `set` is guaranteed to not have duplicates.

Answer (score 51):

To make a new list  retaining the order of first elements of duplicates in `L`:

```
newlist = [ii for n,ii in enumerate(L) if ii not in L[:n]]
```

For example: if `L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5]`, then `newlist` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

This checks each new element has not appeared previously in the list before adding it.
Also it does not need imports.

Comment: This has a time complexity of **O(n ^ 2)**. The answers with `set` and `OrderedDict` may have lower amortized time complexity.

Comment: I used in my code this solution and worked great but I think it is time consuming

Comment: @blubberdiblub can you explain what more code efficient mechanism exists in set and OrderedDict that could make them less time consuming? (excluding the overhead of loading them)

Comment: @iliasiliadis The usual implementations of **set** and **dict** use hashes or (some form of balanced) trees. You have to consider building the **set** or **dict** and searching in it (multiple times), but their amortized complexity usually is still lower than **O(n ^ 2)**. "Amortized" in simple terms means on average (they can have worst cases with higher complexity than the average case). This is only relevant when you have a big number of items.

Comment: Nice answer, it works if the elements are not hashable. However, if the elements are Numpy arrays, you may get surprises, because the `in` operator doesn't work as one might expect (at least as I was expecting).

Answer (score 41):

Super late answer:

If you don't care about the list order, you can use `*arg` expansion with `set` uniqueness to remove duplicates, i.e.:

```
l = [*{*l}]
```

[Python3 Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/f6271c5be5)

Comment: Nice... the one problem is that it's so clever that you kind of have to add a comment to say what it does.

Answer (score 39):

There are also solutions using Pandas and Numpy. They both return numpy array so you have to use the function [`.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) if you want a list.

```
t=['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
t2= ['c','c','b','b','b','a','a','a']
```

### Pandas solution

Using Pandas function [`unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.unique.html):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.unique(t).tolist()
>>>['a','b','c']
pd.unique(t2).tolist()
>>>['c','b','a']
```

### Numpy solution

Using numpy function [`unique()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(t).tolist()
>>>['a','b','c']
np.unique(t2).tolist()
>>>['a','b','c']
```

**Note that numpy.unique() also sort the values**. So the list `t2` is returned sorted. If you want to have the order preserved use as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637336/numpy-unique-with-order-preserved):

```
_, idx = np.unique(t2, return_index=True)
t2[np.sort(idx)].tolist()
>>>['c','b','a']
```

The solution is not so elegant compared to the others, however, compared to pandas.unique(), numpy.unique() allows you also to check if nested arrays are unique along one selected axis.

Comment: This will convert the list to numpy array which is a mess and won't work for strings.

Comment: @user227666 thanks for your review but that's not true it works even with string and you can add .tolist if you want to get a list...

Comment: I think this is kinda like trying to kill a bee with a sledgehammer. Works, sure! But, importing a library for just this purpose might be a little overkill, no?

Comment: @DebosmitRay it could be useful if you work in Data Science where usually you work with numpy and many times you need to work with numpy array.

Comment: the best answer in 2020 
@DebosmitRay i hope you change your mind and use numpy / pandas every time you can

Answer (score 37):

In this answer, there will be two sections: Two unique solutions, and a graph of speed for specific solutions.

### Removing Duplicate Items

Most of these answers only remove duplicate items which are *hashable*, but this question doesn't imply it doesn't just need *hashable* items, meaning I'll offer some solutions which don't require *hashable* items.

`collections.Counter` is a powerful tool in the standard library which could be perfect for this. There's only one other solution which even has Counter in it. However, that solution is also limited to *hashable* keys.

To allow unhashable keys in Counter, I made a Container class, which will try to get the object's default hash function, but if it fails, it will try its identity function. It also defines an **eq** and a **hash** method. This should be enough to allow *unhashable* items in our solution. Unhashable objects will be treated as if they are hashable. However, this hash function uses identity for unhashable objects, meaning two equal objects that are both unhashable won't work. I suggest you override this, and changing it to use the hash of an equivalent mutable type (like using `hash(tuple(my_list))` if `my_list` is a list).

I also made two solutions. Another solution which keeps the order of the items, using a subclass of both OrderedDict and Counter which is named 'OrderedCounter'. Now, here are the functions:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

class Container:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __eq__(self, obj):
        return self.obj == obj
    def __hash__(self):
        try:
            return hash(self.obj)
        except:
            return id(self.obj)

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
     'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'

     def __repr__(self):
         return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

     def __reduce__(self):
         return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)
    
def remd(sequence):
    cnt = Counter()
    for x in sequence:
        cnt[Container(x)] += 1
    return [item.obj for item in cnt]

def oremd(sequence):
    cnt = OrderedCounter()
    for x in sequence:
        cnt[Container(x)] += 1
    return [item.obj for item in cnt]
```

`remd` is non-ordered sorting, while `oremd` is ordered sorting. You can clearly tell which one is faster, but I'll explain anyways. The non-ordered sorting is slightly faster, since it doesn't store the order of the items.

Now, I also wanted to show the speed comparisons of each answer. So, I'll do that now.

### Which Function is the Fastest?

For removing duplicates, I gathered 10 functions from a few answers. I calculated the speed of each function and put it into a graph using *matplotlib.pyplot*.

I divided this into three rounds of graphing. A hashable is any object which can be hashed, an unhashable is any object which cannot be hashed. An ordered sequence is a sequence which preserves order, an unordered sequence does not preserve order. Now, here are a few more terms:

*Unordered Hashable* was for any method which removed duplicates, which didn't necessarily have to keep the order. It didn't have to work for unhashables, but it could.

*Ordered Hashable* was for any method which kept the order of the items in the list, but it didn't have to work for unhashables, but it could.

*Ordered Unhashable* was any method which kept the order of the items in the list, and worked for unhashables.

On the y-axis is the amount of seconds it took.

On the x-axis is the number the function was applied to.

I generated sequences for unordered hashables and ordered hashables with the following comprehension: `[list(range(x)) + list(range(x)) for x in range(0, 1000, 10)]`

For ordered unhashables: `[[list(range(y)) + list(range(y)) for y in range(x)] for x in range(0, 1000, 10)]`

Note there is a `step` in the range because without it, this would've taken 10x as long. Also because in my personal opinion, I thought it might've looked a little easier to read.

Also note the keys on the legend are what I tried to guess as the most vital parts of the implementation of the function. As for what function does the worst or best? The graph speaks for itself.

With that settled, here are the graphs.

#### Unordered Hashables

[image: Unordered Hashables]
(Zoomed in)
[image: Unordered Hashables Zoomed]

#### Ordered Hashables

[image: Ordered Hashables]
(Zoomed in)
[image: Ordered Hashables Zoomed]

### Ordered Unhashables

[image: Ordered Unhashables]
(Zoomed in)
[image: Ordered Unhashables Zoomed]

Comment: Hard to read. Better have a top list at the bottom with the results wrapped up. Thus, for unordered hashables:
**Do not use:**
  #- ii for n,ii in enumerate(seq) if ii not in seq[:n]
  #- cnt = Counter(); cnt[Container(x)] += 1
  #- cnt = OrderedCounter(); cnt[Container(x)) += 1
  #- if i not in new for i in seq.
**Better use:**
  #- list(set(seq))
  #- dict.fromkeys(seq)
  #- added = set(); for in seq: if not val in added
  #- OrderedDict.fromkeys(seq)
  #- OrderedDict((x, True) for x in seq).keys()
  #- functools.reduce(lambda r, v: v in r[1] and r or ... or ..., ([], set[]))[0]

Answer (score 31):

A colleague have sent the accepted answer as part of his code to me for a codereview today.
While I certainly admire the elegance of the answer in question, I am not happy with the performance.
I have tried this solution (I use *set* to reduce lookup time)

```
def ordered_set(in_list):
    out_list = []
    added = set()
    for val in in_list:
        if not val in added:
            out_list.append(val)
            added.add(val)
    return out_list
```

To compare efficiency, I used a random sample of 100 integers - 62 were unique

```
from random import randint
x = [randint(0,100) for _ in xrange(100)]

In [131]: len(set(x))
Out[131]: 62
```

Here are the results of the measurements

```
In [129]: %timeit list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x))
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.4 us per loop

In [130]: %timeit ordered_set(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.1 us per loop
```

Well, what happens if set is removed from the solution?

```
def ordered_set(inlist):
    out_list = []
    for val in inlist:
        if not val in out_list:
            out_list.append(val)
    return out_list
```

The result is not as bad as with the *OrderedDict*, but still more than 3 times of the original solution

```
In [136]: %timeit ordered_set(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.6 us per loop
```

Comment: Nice using set quick lookup to speed up the looped comparison.   If order does not matter list(set(x)) is still 6x faster than this

Comment: @Joop, that was my first question for my colleague - the order does matter; otherwise, it would have been trivial issue

Comment: optimized version of ordered set, for anyone who is interested: `def unique(iterable):` ;`seen = set()`; `seen_add = seen.add`; `return [item for item in iterable if not item in seen and not seen_add(item)]`

Answer (score 23):

Another way of doing:

```
>>> seq = [1,2,3,'a', 'a', 1,2]
>> dict.fromkeys(seq).keys()
['a', 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Note that in modern Python versions (2.7+ I think, but I don't recall for sure), `keys()` returns a dictionary view object, not a list.

Answer (score 22):

Simple and easy:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
cleanlist = []
[cleanlist.append(x) for x in myList if x not in cleanlist]
```

Output:

```
>>> cleanlist 
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: quadratic complexity nonetheless - `in` is O(n) operation and your `cleanlist` will have at most `n` numbers => worst-case ~O(n^2)

Comment: list comprehensions shouldn't be used for side effects.

Answer (score 16):

I had a dict in my list, so I could not use the above approach. I got the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type:
```

So if you care about **order** and/or some items are **unhashable**. Then you might find this useful:

```
def make_unique(original_list):
    unique_list = []
    [unique_list.append(obj) for obj in original_list if obj not in unique_list]
    return unique_list
```

Some may consider list comprehension with a side effect to not be a good solution. Here's an alternative:

```
def make_unique(original_list):
    unique_list = []
    map(lambda x: unique_list.append(x) if (x not in unique_list) else False, original_list)
    return unique_list
```

Comment: `map` with a side effect is even more misleading than a listcomp with a side effect. Also, `lambda x: unique_list.append(x)` is just a clunkier and slower way to pass `unique_list.append`.

Comment: Very useful way to append elements in just one line, thanks!

Comment: @ZLNK please, don't ever use that. Apart from being conceptually ugly, it's also extremely inefficient, because you actually create a potentially large list and throw it away just to perform basic iteration.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to preserve the order, and not use any external modules here is an easy way to do this:

```py
>>> t = [1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9]
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(t))
[1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Note: This method preserves the order of appearance, so, as seen above, nine will come after one because it was the first time it appeared. This however, is the same result as you would get with doing

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
ulist=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(l))
```

but it is much shorter, and runs faster.

This works because each time the `fromkeys` function tries to create a new key, if the value already exists it will simply overwrite it. This wont affect the dictionary at all however, as `fromkeys` creates a dictionary where all keys have the value `None`, so effectively it eliminates all duplicates this way.

Comment: Also try it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_remove_duplicates.asp)

Answer (score 13):

All the order-preserving approaches I've seen here so far either use naive  comparison (with O(n^2) time-complexity at best) or heavy-weight `OrderedDicts`/`set`+`list` combinations that are limited to hashable inputs. Here is a hash-independent O(nlogn) solution:

**Update** added the `key` argument, documentation and Python 3 compatibility.

```
# from functools import reduce <-- add this import on Python 3

def uniq(iterable, key=lambda x: x):
    """
    Remove duplicates from an iterable. Preserves order. 
    :type iterable: Iterable[Ord => A]
    :param iterable: an iterable of objects of any orderable type
    :type key: Callable[A] -> (Ord => B)
    :param key: optional argument; by default an item (A) is discarded 
    if another item (B), such that A == B, has already been encountered and taken. 
    If you provide a key, this condition changes to key(A) == key(B); the callable 
    must return orderable objects.
    """
    # Enumerate the list to restore order lately; reduce the sorted list; restore order
    def append_unique(acc, item):
        return acc if key(acc[-1][1]) == key(item[1]) else acc.append(item) or acc 
    srt_enum = sorted(enumerate(iterable), key=lambda item: key(item[1]))
    return [item[1] for item in sorted(reduce(append_unique, srt_enum, [srt_enum[0]]))]
```

Comment: Yet, this solution requires orderable elements. I will use it uniquify my list of lists: it is a pain to `tuple()` lists and to hash them.  | | | | - Generally speaking, the hash process takes a time proportional to the size of the whole data, while this solution takes a time O(nlog(n)), depending only on the length of the list.

Comment: I think that the set-based approach is equally cheap (O(n log n)), or cheaper, than sorting + detection of uniques. (This approach would parallelize much better, though.) It also does not exactly preserve the initial order, but it gives a predictable order.

Comment: @9000 That is true. I've never mentioned time-complexity of a hash-table-based approach, which is obviously O(n). Here you can find many answers incorporating hash-tables. They are not universal, though, because they require objects to be hashable. Moreover, they are a lot more memory-intensive.

Comment: Takes time to read and understand this answer. 

Is there a point in enumerating when you are not using the indices? 
The `reduce()`  is already working on a sorted collection `srt_enum`, why did you apply `sorted` again?

Comment: @Brayoni the first sort is there to group equal values, the second sort is there to restore initial order. The enumeration is needed to keep track of original relative order.

Answer (score 13):

I've compared the various suggestions with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot). It turns out that, if the input array doesn't have duplicate elements, all methods are more or less equally fast, independently of whether the input data is a Python list or a NumPy array.

[image]

If the input array is large, but contains just one unique element, then the `set`, `dict` and `np.unique` methods are costant-time *if the input data is a list*. If it's a NumPy array, `np.unique` is about 10 times faster than the other alternatives.

[image]

It's somewhat surprising to me that those are not constant-time operations, too.

---

Code to reproduce the plots:

```py
import perfplot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def setup_list(n):
    # return list(np.random.permutation(np.arange(n)))
    return [0] * n


def setup_np_array(n):
    # return np.random.permutation(np.arange(n))
    return np.zeros(n, dtype=int)


def list_set(data):
    return list(set(data))


def numpy_unique(data):
    return np.unique(data)


def list_dict(data):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(data))


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=[
        setup_list,
        setup_list,
        setup_list,
        setup_np_array,
        setup_np_array,
        setup_np_array,
    ],
    kernels=[list_set, numpy_unique, list_dict, list_set, numpy_unique, list_dict],
    labels=[
        "list(set(lst))",
        "np.unique(lst)",
        "list(dict(lst))",
        "list(set(arr))",
        "np.unique(arr)",
        "list(dict(arr))",
    ],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(23)],
    xlabel="len(array)",
    equality_check=None,
)
# plt.title("input array = [0, 1, 2,..., n]")
plt.title("input array = [0, 0,..., 0]")
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Answer (score 10):

You could also do this:

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
>>> s = [x for i, x in enumerate(t) if i == t.index(x)]
>>> s
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The reason that above works is that `index` method returns only the first index of an element. Duplicate elements have higher indices. Refer to [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> **list.index(x[, start[, end]])**
>   Return zero-based index in the list of
>   the first item whose value is x.    Raises a ValueError if there is no
>   such item.

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. `list.index` is a linear-time operation, making your solution quadratic.

Comment: You're right. But also I believe it's fairly obvious the solution is intended to be a one liner that preserves the order. Everything else is already in here.

Answer (score 10):

Best approach of removing duplicates from a list is using **set()** function, available in python, again converting that **set into list**

```
In [2]: some_list = ['a','a','v','v','v','c','c','d']
In [3]: list(set(some_list))
Out[3]: ['a', 'c', 'd', 'v']
```

Comment: @MeetZaveri glad.!

Comment: Instantiating new lists and sets is not free. What happens if we do this many times in quick succession (ie. in a very tight loop), and the lists are very small?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `set` to remove duplicates:

```
mylist = list(set(mylist))
```

But note the results will be unordered. If that's an issue:

```
mylist.sort()
```

Comment: You can just do: mylist = sorted(list(set(mylist)))

Comment: Or `mylist = sorted(set(mylist))`.

Answer (score 8):

Try using sets:

```
import sets
t = sets.Set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
t1 = sets.Set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

print t | t1
print t - t1
```

Answer (score 7):

This one cares about the order without too much hassle (OrderdDict & others). Probably not the most Pythonic way, nor shortest way, but does the trick:

```
def remove_duplicates(item_list):
    ''' Removes duplicate items from a list '''
    singles_list = []
    for element in item_list:
        if element not in singles_list:
            singles_list.append(element)
    return singles_list
```

Comment: 1. You should never shadow builtin names (at least, as important as `list`); 2. Your method scales extremely bad: it is quadratic in the number of elements in `list`.

Comment: 1. Correct, but this was an example; 2. Correct, and that's exactly the reason why I offered it. All solutions posted here have pros and cons. Some sacrifice simplicity or order, mine sacrifices scalability.

Answer (score 7):

One more better approach could be,

```
import pandas as pd

myList = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
cleanList = pd.Series(myList).drop_duplicates().tolist()
print(cleanList)

#> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

and the order remains preserved.

Comment: Though this might work well, using a heavy library like _pandas_ for this purpose seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 6):

Reduce variant with ordering preserve:

Assume that we have list:

```
l = [5, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Reduce variant (unefficient):

```
>>> reduce(lambda r, v: v in r and r or r + [v], l, [])
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

5 x faster but more sophisticated

```
>>> reduce(lambda r, v: v in r[1] and r or (r[0].append(v) or r[1].add(v)) or r, l, ([], set()))[0]
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Explanation:

```
default = (list(), set())
# user list to keep order
# use set to make lookup faster

def reducer(result, item):
    if item not in result[1]:
        result[0].append(item)
        result[1].add(item)
    return result

reduce(reducer, l, default)[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many other answers suggesting different ways to do this, but they're all batch operations, and some of them throw away the original order. That might be okay depending on what you need, but if you want to iterate over the values in the order of the first instance of each value, and you want to remove the duplicates on-the-fly versus all at once, you could use this generator:

```
def uniqify(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            yield item
```

This returns a generator/iterator, so you can use it anywhere that you can use an iterator.

```
for unique_item in uniqify([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 8, 8]):
    print(unique_item, end=' ')

print()
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

---

If you do want a `list`, you can do this:

```
unique_list = list(uniqify([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 8, 8]))

print(unique_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: `seen = set(iterable); for item in seen: yield item` is almost certainly faster. (I haven't tried this specific case, but that would be my guess.)

Comment: @dylnmc, that's a batch operation, and it also loses the ordering. My answer was specifically intended to be on-the-fly and in order of first occurrence. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following function:

```
def rem_dupes(dup_list): 
    yooneeks = [] 
    for elem in dup_list: 
        if elem not in yooneeks: 
            yooneeks.append(elem) 
    return yooneeks
```

**Example**:

```
my_list = ['this','is','a','list','with','dupicates','in', 'the', 'list']
```

**Usage:**

```
rem_dupes(my_list)
```

['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'with', 'dupicates', 'in', 'the']

Comment: Unsuitable for large lists as it creates a duplicate.

Comment: @ingyhere The OP did not suggest anything re: large lists. There is a *always* a tradeoff to every type of implementation, so the premise that every answer must default to "most scalable" is false.

Answer (score 5):

Using ***set*** :

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,3,3,4]
a = list(set(a))
print a
```

Using ***unique*** :

```
import numpy as np
a = [0,1,2,3,4,3,3,4]
a = np.unique(a).tolist()
print a
```

Answer (score 5):

Without using set

```
data=[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
uni_data=[]
for dat in data:
    if dat not in uni_data:
        uni_data.append(dat)

print(uni_data)
```

Answer (score 5):

## The Magic of Python Built-in type

In python, it is very easy to process the complicated cases like this and only by python's built-in type.

Let me show you how to do !

**Method 1: General Case**

The way (*1 line code*) to remove duplicated element in list and still keep sorting order

```
line = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
new_line = sorted(set(line), key=line.index) # remove duplicated element
print(new_line)
```

You will get the result

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

**Method 2: Special Case**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The special case to process unhashable (*3 line codes*)

```
line=[['16.4966155686595', '-27.59776154691', '52.3786295521147']
,['16.4966155686595', '-27.59776154691', '52.3786295521147']
,['17.6508629295574', '-27.143305738671', '47.534955022564']
,['17.6508629295574', '-27.143305738671', '47.534955022564']
,['18.8051102904552', '-26.688849930432', '42.6912804930134']
,['18.8051102904552', '-26.688849930432', '42.6912804930134']
,['19.5504702331098', '-26.205884452727', '37.7709192714727']
,['19.5504702331098', '-26.205884452727', '37.7709192714727']
,['20.2929416861422', '-25.722717575124', '32.8500163147157']
,['20.2929416861422', '-25.722717575124', '32.8500163147157']]

tuple_line = [tuple(pt) for pt in line] # convert list of list into list of tuple
tuple_new_line = sorted(set(tuple_line),key=tuple_line.index) # remove duplicated element
new_line = [list(t) for t in tuple_new_line] # convert list of tuple into list of list

print (new_line)
```

You will get the result :

```
[
  ['16.4966155686595', '-27.59776154691', '52.3786295521147'], 
  ['17.6508629295574', '-27.143305738671', '47.534955022564'], 
  ['18.8051102904552', '-26.688849930432', '42.6912804930134'], 
  ['19.5504702331098', '-26.205884452727', '37.7709192714727'], 
  ['20.2929416861422', '-25.722717575124', '32.8500163147157']
]
```

Because tuple is hashable and you can convert data between list and tuple easily

Answer (score 4):

below code is simple for removing duplicate in list

```
def remove_duplicates(x):
    a = []
    for i in x:
        if i not in a:
            a.append(i)
    return a

print remove_duplicates([1,2,2,3,3,4])
```

it returns [1,2,3,4]

Comment: If you don't care about order, then this takes significantly longer. `list(set(..))` (over 1 million passes) will beat this solution by about 10 whole seconds - whereas this approach takes about 12 seconds, `list(set(..))` only takes about 2 seconds!

Comment: @dylnmc this is also a duplicate of a significantly older [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25622503/3846213)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the fastest pythonic solution comaring to others listed in replies.

Using implementation details of short-circuit evaluation allows to use list comprehension, which is fast enough. `visited.add(item)` always returns `None` as a result, which is evaluated as `False`, so the right-side of `or` would always be the result of such an expression.

Time it yourself

```
def deduplicate(sequence):
    visited = set()
    adder = visited.add  # get rid of qualification overhead
    out = [adder(item) or item for item in sequence if item not in visited]
    return out
```

Answer (score 4):

Very simple way in Python 3:

```
>>> n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1]
>>> n
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1]
>>> m = sorted(list(set(n)))
>>> m
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `sorted(list(...))` is redundant (`sorted` already implicitly converts its argument to a new `list`, sorts it, then returns the new `list`, so using both means making an unnecessary temporary `list`). Use only `list` if the result need not be sorted, use only `sorted` if the result needs to be sorted.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately. Most answers here either do not preserve the order or are too long. Here is a simple, order preserving answer.

```
s = [1,2,3,4,5,2,5,6,7,1,3,9,3,5]
x=[]

[x.append(i) for i in s if i not in x]
print(x)
```

This will give you x with duplicates removed but preserving the order.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, returning list without repetiotions preserving order. Does not need any external imports.

```
def GetListWithoutRepetitions(loInput):
    # return list, consisting of elements of list/tuple loInput, without repetitions.
    # Example: GetListWithoutRepetitions([None,None,1,1,2,2,3,3,3])
    # Returns: [None, 1, 2, 3]

    if loInput==[]:
        return []

    loOutput = []

    if loInput[0] is None:
        oGroupElement=1
    else: # loInput[0]<>None
        oGroupElement=None

    for oElement in loInput:
        if oElement<>oGroupElement:
            loOutput.append(oElement)
            oGroupElement = oElement
    return loOutput
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this if you want to remove duplicates (in-place edit rather than returning new list) without using inbuilt set, dict.keys, uniqify, counter

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> for i in t:
...     if i in t[t.index(i)+1:]:
...         t.remove(i)
... 
>>> t
[3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Use `enumerate()` to get the index faster: `for i, value in enumerate(t): if value in t[i + 1:]: t.remove(value)`

Answer (score 2):

I think converting to set is the easiest way to remove duplicate:

```
list1 = [1,2,1]
list1 = list(set(list1))
print list1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def remove_duplicates(A):
   [A.pop(idx) for idx,elem in enumerate(A) if A.count(elem)!=1]
   return A
```

A list comprehesion to remove duplicates

Comment: Love the simplicity, for small lists this will work fine. I'd be tempted to not use 'count' for the index, but eg 'idx'. like: [A.pop(idx) for idx,elem in enumerate(A) if A.count(elem)!=1]

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see answers for non-hashable values, one liner, n log n, standard-library only, so here's my answer:

```
list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.groupby(sorted(items))))
```

Or as a generator function:

```
def unique(items: Iterable[T]) -> Iterable[T]:
    """For unhashable items (can't use set to unique) with a partial order"""
    yield from map(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.groupby(sorted(items)))
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the duplicates, make it a SET and then again make it a LIST and print/use it.
A set is guaranteed to have unique elements. For example :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,9,11,15]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
c=a+b
print c
print list(set(c)) #one line for getting unique elements of c
```

The output will be as follows (checked in python 2.7)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 11, 15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  #simple list addition with duplicates
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15] #duplicates removed!!
```

Answer (score 1):

It requires installing a 3rd-party module but the package `iteration_utilities` contains a [`unique_everseen`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/cfuncs.html#iteration_utilities.unique_everseen)<sup>1</sup> function that can remove all duplicates while preserving the order:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import unique_everseen

>>> list(unique_everseen(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] + ['a', 'c', 'd']))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

In case you want to avoid the overhead of the list addition operation you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) instead:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(unique_everseen(chain(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd'])))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

The `unique_everseen` also works if you have unhashable items (for example lists) in the lists:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import unique_everseen
>>> list(unique_everseen([['a'], ['b'], 'c', 'd'] + ['a', 'c', 'd']))
[['a'], ['b'], 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

However that will be (much) slower than if the items are hashable.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure: I'm the author of the `iteration_utilities`-library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by using sets.

**Step1:** Get Different elements of lists 
**Step2** Get Common elements of lists 
**Step3** Combine them

```
In [1]: a = ["apples", "bananas", "cucumbers"]

In [2]: b = ["pears", "apples", "watermelons"]

In [3]: set(a).symmetric_difference(b).union(set(a).intersection(b))
Out[3]: {'apples', 'bananas', 'cucumbers', 'pears', 'watermelons'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about order and want something different than the pythonic ways suggested above (that is, it can be used in interviews) then :

```
def remove_dup(arr):
    size = len(arr)
    j = 0    # To store index of next unique element
    for i in range(0, size-1):
        # If current element is not equal
        # to next element then store that
        # current element
        if(arr[i] != arr[i+1]):
            arr[j] = arr[i]
            j+=1

    arr[j] = arr[size-1] # Store the last element as whether it is unique or repeated, it hasn't stored previously

    return arr[0:j+1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
    print(remove_dup(sorted(arr)))
```

Time Complexity : O(n)

Auxiliary Space : O(n)

Reference: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-sorted-array/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers here that use a `set(..)` (which is fast given the elements are *hashable*), or a list (which has the downside that it results in an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm.

The function I propose is a hybrid one: we use a `set(..)` for items that *are* hashable, and a `list(..)` for the ones that are not. Furthermore it is implemented as a *generator* such that we can for instance limit the number of items, or do some additional filtering.

Finally we also can use a `key` argument to specify in what way the elements should be unique. For instance we can use this if we want to filter a list of strings such that every string in the output has a different length.

```
def uniq(iterable, key=lambda x: x):
    seens = set()
    seenl = []
    for item in iterable:
        k = key(item)
        try:
            seen = k in seens
        except TypeError:
            seen = k in seenl
        if not seen:
            yield item
            try:
                seens.add(k)
            except TypeError:
                seenl.append(k)
```

We can now for instance use this like:

```
>>> list(uniq(["apple", "pear", "banana", "lemon"], len))
['apple', 'pear', 'banana']
>>> list(uniq(["apple", "pear", "lemon", "banana"], len))
['apple', 'pear', 'banana']
>>> list(uniq(["apple", "pear", {}, "lemon", [], "banana"], len))
['apple', 'pear', {}, 'banana']
>>> list(uniq(["apple", "pear", {}, "lemon", [], "banana"]))
['apple', 'pear', {}, 'lemon', [], 'banana']
>>> list(uniq(["apple", "pear", {}, "lemon", {}, "banana"]))
['apple', 'pear', {}, 'lemon', 'banana']
```

It is thus a uniqeness filter that can work on any iterable and filter out uniques, regardless whether these are hashable or not.

It makes one assumption: that if one object is hashable, and another one is not, the two objects are never equal. This can strictly speaking happen, although it would be very uncommon.

Comment: A note: There are built-ins that will break the assumption stated in the final paragraph; `frozenset` is hashable, `set` is not, and if they have the same values, they're equal, but you'll treat them as non-equal in this code.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes, I agree with that, like said it does not solve *all* the problems. Nevertheless, by using a `set(..)` this will simply not work at all, and by using a `list`, this will result in linear lookup time. So it is meant as a "better" set, but with some pitfalls.

Comment: Furhermore a `set(..)` also in rare cases returns objects that are not equal. For example `math.nan` is not equal to `math.nan`, but the dictionary will return it, since it checks first for *reference equality*.

Comment: Instead of using `key=lambda x: x`, you could use `key=None` and put in `k = key(item) if key else item`. This should be a tiny bit faster and yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be the following. Create a dictionary out of the list with item as key and index as value, and then print the dictionary keys.

```
>>> lst = [1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 21, 1, 32, 21, 1, 6, 5, 7, 8, 2]
>>>
>>> dict_enum = {item:index for index, item in enumerate(lst)}
>>> print dict_enum.keys()
[32, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 21]
```

Comment: Why compute/store the index if you never use it? This looks like a solution intended to preserve order (by storing last seen index of each value) that forgot to do so. `list(set(lst))` would achieve the same logical result.

Comment: You could just do `list(dict.fromkeys(lst))`

Answer (score 1):

I did this with pure python function. This works when your `items` value is JSON.

```
[i for n, i in enumerate(items) if i not in items[n + 1 :]]
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can **remove duplicates** using a Python **set or the dict.fromkeys()** method.
- The **dict.fromkeys()** method **converts** a **list into a dictionary**. **Dictionaries** cannot contain **duplicate** values so a dictionary with only unique values is returned by dict.fromkeys().
- **Sets**, like dictionaries, cannot contain **duplicate values**. If we convert a **list to a set**, all the **duplicates are removed**.

###### **Method 1: The naive approach**

```py
mylist = [5, 10, 15, 20, 3, 15, 25, 20, 30, 10, 100]

uniques = []

for i in mylist:

    if i not in uniques:

       uniques.append(i)

print(uniques)
```

###### **Method 2: Using set()**

```py
mylist = [5, 10, 15, 20, 3, 15, 25, 20, 30, 10, 100]

myset = set(mylist)

print(list(myset))
```

Comment: Passing via set() preserve list order?

Answer (score 1):

Using set, but preserving order

```
unique = set()
[unique.add(n) or n for n in l if n not in unique]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can remove duplicates from a list or other iterable using a few different methods. Here are some common approaches :

1. **Using a Set (Recommended for Lists):**

```py
original_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
unique_list = list(set(original_list))
```

2. **Using a List Comprehension:**

```py
original_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
unique_list = [x for x in original_list if original_list.count(x) == 1]
```

3. **Using a for Loop:**

```py
original_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
unique_list = []
for item in original_list:
    if item not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(item)
```

4. **Using the itertools Library:**

```py
from itertools import groupby

original_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
unique_list = [k for k, _ in groupby(original_list)]
```

5. **Using List Comprehension and Enumerate**

```py
original_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
unique_list =  [a for i,a in enumerate(original_list) if a not in original_list[i+1:]]
```

6. **Using set() and Sorting**

```py
original_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
unique_list = sorted(set(original_list), key=original_list[::-1].index)[::-1]
```

7. **Using dict.fromkeys()**

```py
original_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
unique_list = list(dict.fromkeys(original_list[::-1]))[::-1]
```

> In programming, there are often multiple solutions to a problem, and in the end, they all yield the same result

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work as intended; it only returns items that were used once. Any duplicated items will be left out entirely.

Comment: Option 4 doesn't deduplicate at all.

Comment: @JerodG It seems to me that you have not tried them and they work well

Comment: Option 4 doesn't work if the data is unsorted

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, and since this is a very popular question, the [toolz](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library offers a [`unique`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique) function:

```
>>> tuple(unique((1, 2, 3)))
(1, 2, 3)
>>> tuple(unique((1, 2, 1, 3)))
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_duplicates(input_list):
  if input_list == []:
    return []
  #sort list from smallest to largest
  input_list=sorted(input_list)
  #initialize ouput list with first element of the       sorted input list
  output_list = [input_list[0]]
  for item in input_list:
    if item >output_list[-1]:
      output_list.append(item)
  return output_list
```

Comment: Rather than putting the row code in this way, can you explain what your code does?

Answer (score 0):

this is just a readable funtion ,easily understandable ,and i have used the dict data structure,i have used some builtin funtions and a better complexity of O(n)

```
def undup(dup_list):
    b={}
    for i in dup_list:
        b.update({i:1})
    return b.keys()
a=["a",'b','a']
print undup(a)
```

disclamer: u may get an indentation error(if copy and paste) ,use the above code with proper indentation before pasting

Comment: You could just do `list(dict.fromkeys(dup_list))`

Answer (score 0):

Python has built-in many functions You can use set() to remove the duplicate inside the list.
As per your example there are below two lists t and t2

```
t = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
t2 = ['a', 'c', 'd']
result = list(set(t) - set(t2))
result
```

Answer: ['b']

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to remove the duplicate items in-place, without creating new list. For example, the list is big, or keep it as a shadow copy

```
from collections import Counter
cntDict = Counter(t)
for item,cnt in cntDict.items():
    for _ in range(cnt-1):
        t.remove(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is ordered, you can use the following approach to iterate over it skipping the repeated values. This is especially useful to handle big lists with low memory consumption evading the cost of building a `dict` or a `set`:

```
def uniq(iterator):
    prev = None
    for item in iterator:
        if item != prev:
            prev = item
            yield item
```

Then:

```
for item in uniq([1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6]):
    print(item, end=' ')
```

The output is going to be: `1 3 5 6`

To return a list object, you could do:

```
>>> print(list(uniq([1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6])))
[1, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: My answer details a more efficient way of skipping repeated values when the constraint of having a pre-ordered list is appreciated

Comment: This only catches duplicates in an ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the length of the set and the list and save the set items to list.

```
if len(t) != len(set(t)):
    t = [x for x in set(t)]
```

Answer (score 0):

IF ...

1. the order of deletion matters
2. you want to do this in-place

... then this function may be interesting for you. Note I've not optimized anything, it's not very Pythonic and all that, and it's better to handle such stuff during collection of the data, but still, imagine you have a bunch of collected objects and want to get rid of the earlier (fifo) or later (lifo) objects that are in fact duplicates ... -

```
def remove_list_duplicates( lst, fifo=False ):
  idx = 0 ; incr = 1 ; stopidx = len( lst )
  if not fifo:
    idx = stopidx - 1 ; stopidx = incr = -1
  while idx != stopidx:
    elem = lst[idx]
    if lst.count(elem) > 1:
      lst.pop( idx )
      if fifo:
        stopidx -= 1 ; idx -= 1
    idx += incr
```

Applying like this:

```
seq = [1,2,3,4,3,8,1,5,1]
print( 'inp', seq )
remove_list_duplicates( seq, True )
print( 'fifo', seq )
seq = [1,2,3,4,3,8,1,5,1]
remove_list_duplicates( seq, False )
print( 'lifo', seq )
```

Delivers:

```
inp [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 8, 1, 5, 1]
fifo [2, 4, 3, 8, 5, 1]
lifo [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Test = [1,8,2,7,3,4,5,1,2,3,6]
Test.sort()
i=1
while i< len(Test):
  if Test[i] == Test[i-1]:
    Test.remove(Test[i])
  i= i+1
print(Test)
```

Answer (score -2):

## Check for the string 'a' and 'b'

```
clean_list = []
    for ele in raw_list:
        if 'b' in ele or 'a' in ele:
            pass
        else:
            clean_list.append(ele)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Write a Python program to create a list of numbers by taking input from the user and then remove  the duplicates from the list. You can take input of non-zero numbers, with an appropriate  prompt, from the user until the user enters a zero to create the list assuming that the numbers  are non-zero.  
Sample Input: [10, 34, 18, 10, 12, 34, 18, 20, 25, 20]  
Output: [10, 34, 18, 12, 20, 25] 

 lst = []
print("ENTER ZERO NUMBER FOR EXIT !!!!!!!!!!!!")
print("ENTER LIST ELEMENTS  :: ")
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0 :
       print("!!!!!!!!!!! EXIT !!!!!!!!!!!!")
       break
    else :
        lst.append(n)
print("LIST ELEMENR ARE :: ",lst)
#dup = set()
uniq = []
for x in lst:
    if x not in uniq:
        uniq.append(x)
       # dup.add(x)
print("UNIQUE ELEMENTS IN LIST ARE :: ",uniq)
```

Comment: What's the point of the double loop? You can already do the `if x not in` check when taking the input. i.e. `if n not in lst: lst.append(n)` inside the `while True` loop and then `lst` will already have the result. No need for `uniq` at all...