# how does "not x" in python set method works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im new to Python3.3 and i wanted to eliminate repetitive members from a list, i found this short code on the net , but i don't know what is the logic behind this code? ,especially the part "not seen_add(x)"!.

```
def f7(seq):
    seen=set()
    seen_add=seen.add
    return[x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]
```

can someone clear this up for me?!

Comment: The set.add() always returns None.
More info about your code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4463433/2334951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add` method of a set always returns `None`. `None` is considered false in a boolean context, so `not seen_add(x)` is always `True`. `and` short-circuits, so `seen_add(x)` is only executed if x wasn't registered as seen. The `seen_add(x)` is to keep track of the fact that x has now been seen, not to filter anything, which is why `not seen_add(x)` is always true.

Turning the list comprehension into an equivalent loop, we have

```
def f7(seq):
    seen=set()
    seen_add=seen.add
    result = []
    for x in seq:
        if x not in seen and not seen_add(x):
            result.append(x)
    return result
```

Converting the `and` to a more readable form, and eliminating the `seen_add` microoptimization, the code you found is equivalent to the following:

```
def f7(seq):
    seen=set()
    result = []
    for x in seq:
        if x not in seen:
            seen.add(x)
            result.append(x)
    return result
```

Comment: So it's the same thing as `list(set(seq))`? :P

Comment: @shambulator: No, because this code takes special care to make sure the output is ordered by the first occurence of each element in the input. `list(set(seq))` is something you'd use if you didn't care about order.

Comment: @shambulator It's basically a golfed version of the `unique_everseen` recipe from itertools. You'll also see `list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(seq))` crop up a bit for this as well.