# Why the map function doesn't return the list without duplicate elements?

Tags: python-2.7, list, python-3.4

I have this list:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 56, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

And I wat to get rid of duplicate values. The code for the `map` function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459748/111110). 
this is the complete testing code:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 56, 6, 6, 6, 7]

list2 = []
map(lambda x: not x in list2 and list2.append(x), list1)
print(list2)

list2 = []
[list2.append(c) for c in list1 if c not in list2]
print(list2)

list2 = []

for c in list1:
    if c not in list2:
        list2.append(c)

print(list2)
```

In Python 2.7 is prints:

> ```
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]
> ```

In Python 3.4 it prints:

> ```
> []
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]
> ```

Why the `map` function returns an empty list in Python3?

Comment: Why don't you use `np.unique` ?

Comment: Because this is not a production code, this is for learning purposes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) a `map` is **not evaluate immediately**. It works as a generator where elements are generated on the fly *by need*: this can be more efficient since it is possible you for instance only need the first three elements so why would you calculate all elements? So as long as you do not **materialize** the output of `map` in a way, you have not really calculated the map.

You can for instance use `list(..)` to force Python to evaluate the list:

```
list(map(lambda x: not x in list2 and list2.append(x), list1))
```

In that case [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) will generate the same result for `list2`.