# Python len() function Not returning the original length as my mapped list contain Some duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
scores = list(set(map(int, input().split())))
    l = len(scores)
    print(l)
```

## input given

**100 100 50 40 40 20 10**

## output

**5**

## Question

output should be 7 but Why it is 5?

Comment: Why are you using set? Why do you *think* the length should be 7? There's only 5 items in the set, and you make a list out of that set, so the list will have 5 items..

Comment: You'd benefit from reading [How to make lists contain only distinct element in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4459703/364696).

Comment: By calling set() you are removing duplicates, in this case "100" and "40", leaving you with 5 numbers

Comment: The very definition of a "set" is that it doesn't have duplicate values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the len() function returned you the result is 5 because when you are using set() it's removing duplicates entries so in your case it's counting 40 40 and 100 100 as one entry to avoid this you can simply use list() without the set()

```
scores = list(map(int, input().split()))
l = len(scores)
print(l)
```

or

```
*scores, = map(int, input().split())
l = len(scores)
print(l)
```

Comment: The first line in your second block isn't legal. If you want a `list`, you need the brackets, `scores = [*map(int, input().split())]` or you need the `*` on the other side and a comma, `*scores, = map(int, input().split())`

Answer (score -1):

DO not use set there is no use of set

```
scores = list(map(int, input().split()))
    l = len(scores)
   print(l)
```